# How to measure the rate of decrease or increase of a particular stock in a specific time period

Tags: percentages, slope

I need to measure the drop or increase of the value of a stock within a specific time frame. For example given a company XYZ, I need a formula to calculate the percentage change in value for stock XYZ from day 1 to day 10 (i.e. +10% or -5%).

So I think I have provide the time frame and the starting and ending values, but I am not sure about the formula itself

Comment: Can't you just calculate the percent change and divide by the time period?

Comment: This sounds like a step in the homework problem for VBA from the data analytics bootcamp that I am enrolled in.  Either way, when talking about percentages you need to always be clear about "percentages *of what*."  You could talk about what percentage the final closing price is of the original opening price, which would be $\frac{\text{final}}{\text{opening}}$, or what seems more likely that you are after is what percentage the difference of the final and opening price is compared to the opening price: $\frac{\text{final - opening}}{\text{opening}}$.  The time frame plays no role whatsoever.

Comment: If you really were wanting to talk about the *rate* of increase, then you would divide by the length of time for the interval, so supposing the stock opened at a value of $100$ on the first day and closed at a value of $110$ on the tenth day, it would be $\frac{110-100}{100}=10$ percent increased total and $\frac{10}{10}=1$ percent increased per day on average.